# How to populate data in a dynamic Excel ListObject table?

Tags: excel, vba

For a project portfolio resource report, I need to summarize data from flat data worksheet into a ListObject table. Today the process is done ‘statically’ in VBA e.g. when a new resource in either of the unit tables (see picture be-low) is added the ‘static’ VBA must also be updated manually by adding a new cell reference. I need to make this procedure dynamic.

The static code exploits the ListObject table functionality by copying the cell formula from the first cell of each table (7 tables in total) to the other cells in the table.

```
Sub FormaterResArk()

Dim List As Excel.ListObject

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Ark3.Cells.ClearContents ‘Ark3 is the Resource report worksheet where the ListObject tables reside
    
'********** Static code **********
Range("G3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
 ‘ResSkyggeArk is the flat datafile worksheet name
"=ResSkyggeArk!RC+ResSkyggeArk!R[119]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[238]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[357]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[476]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[595]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[714]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[833]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[952]C"
    Range("G3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("H3:R3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
Range("G14").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=ResSkyggeArk!RC+ResSkyggeArk!R[119]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[238]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[357]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[476]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[595]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[714]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[833]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[952]C"
    Range("G14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("H14:R14").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
Range("G27").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=ResSkyggeArk!RC+ResSkyggeArk!R[119]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[238]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[357]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[476]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[595]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[714]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[833]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[952]C"
    Range("G27").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("H27:R27").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("G59").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=ResSkyggeArk!RC+ResSkyggeArk!R[119]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[238]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[357]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[476]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[595]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[714]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[833]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[952]C"
    Range("G59").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("H59:R59").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
Range("G71").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=ResSkyggeArk!RC+ResSkyggeArk!R[119]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[238]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[357]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[476]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[595]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[714]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[833]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[952]C"
    Range("G71").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("H71:R71").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("G80").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=ResSkyggeArk!RC+ResSkyggeArk!R[119]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[238]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[357]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[476]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[595]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[714]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[833]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[952]C"
    Range("G80").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("H80:R80").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
Range("G92").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=ResSkyggeArk!RC+ResSkyggeArk!R[119]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[238]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[357]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[476]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[595]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[714]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[833]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[952]C"
    Range("G92").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("H92:R92").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
'********** Marks resource if > 135 hrs red and hrs between 128 og 134,9 yellow **********
    Range("G3:R11,G14:R24,G27:R56,G59:R68,G71:R77,G80:R89,G92:R113").Select

    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
        Formula1:="=135"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Italic = False
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=128", Formula2:="=134,9"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Italic = False
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    

'********** Hides filter-buttons from tables **********
    For Each List In Ark3.ListObjects
        List.ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False
    Next
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

(both files can be DL from here: https://gofile.io/d/GL86kd) The ListObject table is automatically updated when the workbook is opened and looks like this:

[image: Resource report worksheet]

The flat data sheet that serves as data-source looks like this (exactly the same structure for each project i.e. it repeats itself with the number of projects):

[image: DataTable worksheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a simple loop solution. It still make use of the ListObject table properties in combination with the power of FormulaR1C1. The formmula itself is very long, but I tried various nested loops here as well who all failed. Here's the code:

```
Sub LavSamletResArk()

   Dim WS As Worksheet
   Dim tbl As ListObject
   Dim sidsteraekke As Long
   Dim X As Long
   Dim r As Long
      
   Set WS = Ark3
   'Find the last row number of the resource report    
   sidsteraekke = Ark3.Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row 
   
   r = sidsteraekke
   
   'Write formula into cells
   For Each tbl In WS.ListObjects
       For X = 1 To tbl.ListRows.count
           tbl.Range.Cells(2, 7).Select
           ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ResSkyggeArk!RC+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & r & _ 
           "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 2 * r & "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 3 * r & _ 
           "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 4 * r & "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 5 * r &  _ 
           "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 6 * r & "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 7 * r &  _ 
           "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 8 * r & "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 9 * r &  _ 
           "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 10 * r & "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 11 * r & _ 
           "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 12 * r & "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 13 * r & _ 
           "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 14 * r & "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 15 * r & "]C _        
           +ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 16 * r & "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 17 * r & _ 
           "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 18 * r & "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 19 * r & _ 
           "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 20 * r & "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 21 * r &  _ 
           "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 22 * r & "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 23 * r & "]C _ 
           +ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 24 * r & "]C+ResSkyggeArk!R[" & 25 * r & "]C"
           ActiveCell.Copy
           ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
           Range(ActiveCell, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
           ActiveSheet.Paste
           Application.CutCopyMode = False
         Exit For
       Next X
   Next tbl
End Sub
```